# How to extract text from a string after the first instance of repetition is detected?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to extract the original phrase from a string, in an excel cell.

For example, i've got this string in a cell: 
"mary has a little lamb mary has a little lamb mary has a little lamb..."

I want to extract the original phrase, "mary has a little lamb".

How can i do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything? You tagged VBA so I assume you have some code to show? Tell us where it fails/errors out/doesn't do what you intended it do do. :)

Comment: Does your actual text contain *only* repetitions like your example, or is it more complex than what you show?

Comment: more sample sentences to cover all possible combination of words please

Answer (score 0):

Try this;
Assuming you have the string "mary has a little lamb mary has a little lamb mary has a little lamb..." in Cell B2, the formula 
=MID(B2,1,SEARCH(MID(B2,1,FIND(" ", B2)-1),B2,FIND(" ", B2))-2) will give you the desired result. 
This formula has a limitation that the first word does not repeat within the original phrase.

Comment: If you have words that occur more than once in your original phrase, eg. B2 contains "mary little has a little lamb mary little has a little lamb mary little has a little lamb mary little has a little lamb...", then use the formula =MID(B2,1,SEARCH("mary little",B2,2)-2). To use this with any other example, the string "mary little" in this formula should be replaced with a uniquely occurring string, starting with 1st letter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the question is actually about VBA, you can use InStr(FullText, SearchedText) to get the position of the first sought text string within a string.

```
Sub LambHunting()
 A = "mary has a little lamb"
 B = "mary has a little lamb mary has a little lamb mary has a little lamb..."
 C = "Mary HAD a little lamb; unfortunately mary has a little lamb no longer."
 Debug.Print "'" & A & "' is at position #" & InStr(B, A) & " in the string '" & B & "'"
 Debug.Print "'" & A & "' is at position #" & InStr(C, A) & " in the string '" & C & "'"
End Sub
```

Returns:

```
'mary has a little lamb' is at position #1 in the string 'mary has a little lamb mary has a little lamb mary has a little lamb...'
'mary has a little lamb' is at position #39 in the string 'Mary HAD a little lamb; unfortunately mary has a little lamb no longer.'
```